# Mostrar datos con Eager loading laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

tengo un pequeño problema, espero si me puedan ayudar a resolverlo.

Estoy intentando cargar los datos de `question` y `answers` con eager loading para mostrarlo, pero me genera el siguiente error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Las relaciones en los modelos.

`Question.php`

```
class Question extends Model{
  protected $fillable = [
    'questionnaire_id' ,'category_id', 'description', 'iframe', 'image',
  ];

  protected $guarded = [];

  public function questionnaire(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Questionnaire::class);
  }

  public function answers(){
    return $this->hasMany(Answer::class);
  }
}
```

En el modelo `Questionnaire.php`

```
class Questionnaire extends Model{
  protected $fillable =['title', 'description', 'user_id'];
  
  protected $guarded = [];
  
  public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
  }

  public function questions(){
    return $this->hasMany(Question::class);
  }
}
```

Y en el metodo de QuestionnaireController, lo llamo en el método show
El cual intente con `with()` y `load()`

Con with me genera este error.
`QuestionController`

```
public function show(Questionnaire $questionnaires){
    $questionnaires = Questionnaire::with('questions')->get();
    return view('questionnaire.show', compact('questionnaires'));
}
```

Y con el load me regresa la vista vacia.

```
public function show(Questionnaire $questionnaires){
    $questionnaires->load('questions.answers'); 
    return view('questionnaire.show', compact('questionnaires'));
}
```

También adjunto mi vista

`view.blade.php`

```
 @foreach ($questionnaires->questions as $question)
   <div class="card-body">
     <span class="text-muted">{{ $question->id }}-.</span> {{ $question->description }}
   </div>
 @endforeach
```

Comment: El primero debería ser questionnaires->questions as questions y el segundo es questions as question?

Comment: @BetaM Así es, Questionnaire es el "examen" que contiene las preguntas y respuestas. Estuve intentando trabajar con el método load pero aun no logro que arroje los resultados.

Comment: Claro, mientras seguiré moviéndole a esto para que funcione xD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al momento tu consulta te puede estar regresando:

- Una colección de los objetos de `Questionnaire`
- Otra colección de los objetos de la relación de `questions`
- Una colección de los objetos de la relación de `answers`

Entonces puedes usar esta query:

```
$data = Questionnaire::with('questions.answers')->get();
```

Dado lo anterior entonces ocupamos:

- 3 ciclos `foreach`, uno por cada a colección a recorrer, con una estructura como esta:

  ```
    @foreach($data as $questionnaire)
        {{ $questionnaire->propiedad }} //propiedades de questionnaire
        @foreach($questionnaire->questions as $question)
            {{ $question->propiedad }} //propiedades de questions
            @foreach($question->answers as $answer)
                {{ $answer->propiedad }} //propiedades de answers
            @endforeach
        @endforeach
    @endforeach
  ```

Como extra, *aunque no lo uso* para el caso de [`load`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-collections#method-load) deberás primero:

- (*Basados en tus consulta*), obtener todos los modelos de `Questionnaire` y posterior entonces solicitar la carga de las relaciones, que como notas en el enlace aquí provisto también acepta relaciones anidadas.

Quedando así:

```
$data = Questionnaire:all();
$valores = $data->load('questions.answers');
```

Lo demás queda igual en cuanto a recorrerlo (*al menos con la propuesta actual*)

*Créditos a [Marcin Navialek](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47868744/laravel-eager-loading-using-with-vs-load-after-creating-the-parent-model)* de cuya respuesta me apoye para agregar el último segmento sobre el método **`load`**

Comment: Lo implemente y funciono. Aunque tengo una duda, con el método `Questionnaire->load('questions.answers')` no se puede lograr lo mismo?

Comment: Muchas gracias viejo. Voy a leerme el hilo e investigare más.